# How do I know when it's safe to call Dispose?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose, race-condition

I have a search application that takes some time (10 to 15 seconds) to return results for some requests. It's not uncommon to have multiple concurrent requests for the same information. As it stands, I have to process those independently, which makes for quite a bit of unnecessary processing.

I've come up with a design that should allow me to avoid the unnecessary processing, but there's one lingering problem.

Each request has a key that identifies the data being requested. I maintain a dictionary of requests, keyed by the request key. The request object has some state information and a `WaitHandle` that is used to wait on the results.

When a client calls my `Search` method, the code checks the dictionary to see if a request already exists for that key. If so, the client just waits on the `WaitHandle`. If no request exists, I create one, add it to the dictionary, and issue an asynchronous call to get the information. Again, the code waits on the event.

When the asynchronous process has obtained the results, it updates the request object, removes the request from the dictionary, and then signals the event.

This all works great. Except I don't know when to dispose of the request object. That is, since I don't know when the last client is using it, I can't call `Dispose` on it. I have to wait for the garbage collector to come along and clean up.

Here's the code:

```
class SearchRequest: IDisposable
{
    public readonly string RequestKey;
    public string Results { get; set; }
    public ManualResetEvent WaitEvent { get; private set; }

    public SearchRequest(string key)
    {
        RequestKey = key;
        WaitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        WaitEvent.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

ConcurrentDictionary<string, SearchRequest> Requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SearchRequest>();

string Search(string key)
{
    SearchRequest req;
    bool addedNew = false;
    req = Requests.GetOrAdd(key, (s) =>
        {
            // Create a new request.
            var r = new SearchRequest(s);
            Console.WriteLine("Added new request with key {0}", key);
            addedNew = true;
            return r;
        });

    if (addedNew)
    {
        // A new request was created.
        // Start a search.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
            {
                // Get the results
                req.Results = DoSearch(req.RequestKey);  // DoSearch takes several seconds

                // Remove the request from the pending list
                SearchRequest trash;
                Requests.TryRemove(req.RequestKey, out trash);

                // And signal that the request is finished
                req.WaitEvent.Set();
            });
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for results from request with key {0}", key);
    req.WaitEvent.WaitOne();
    return req.Results;
}
```

Basically, I don't know when the last client will be released. No matter how I slice it here, I have a race condition. Consider:

1. Thread A Creates a new request, starts Thread 2, and waits on the wait handle.
2. Thread B Begins processing the request.
3. Thread C detects that there's a pending request, and then gets swapped out.
4. Thread B Completes the request, removes the item from the dictionary, and sets the event.
5. Thread A's wait is satisfied, and it returns the result.
6. Thread C wakes up, calls `WaitOne`, is released, and returns the result.

If I use some kind of reference counting so that the "last" client calls `Dispose`, then the object would be disposed by Thread A in the above scenario. Thread C would then die when it tried to wait on the disposed `WaitHandle`.

The only way I can see to fix this is to use a reference counting scheme and protect access to the dictionary with a lock (in which case using `ConcurrentDictionary` is pointless) so that a lookup is always accompanied by an increment of the reference count. Whereas that would work, it seems like an ugly hack.

Another solution would be to ditch the `WaitHandle` and use an event-like mechanism with callbacks. But that, too, would require me to protect the lookups with a lock, and I have the added complication of dealing with an event or a naked multicast delegate. That seems like a hack, too.

This probably isn't a problem currently, because this application doesn't yet get enough traffic for those abandoned handles to add up before the next GC pass comes and cleans them up. And maybe it won't ever be a problem? It worries me, though, that I'm leaving them to be cleaned up by the GC when I should be calling `Dispose` to get rid of them.

Ideas? Is this a potential problem? If so, do you have a clean solution?

Comment: one word springs to mind: "Eeeeeek!!"

Comment: @Mitch: what is the "Eeeeeek" in response to? The design? Or the problem?

Comment: @Jim Mischel - You need to keep in mind that `ConcurrentDictionary` does have side-effects. If multiple threads try to call `GetOrAdd` at the same time then the factory can be invoked for all of them, but only one will win. The values produced for the other threads will just be discarded, however by then the compute has been done.

Comment: @Jim Mischel - Also you mentioned that the GC would do your clean up, but the GC never calls `.Dispose()` - you always have to call `.Dispose()` explicitly in your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I know that the GC doesn't call `Dispose`, but it does execute the finalizer. And the finalizer for `ManualResetEvent` calls `Dispose`, which frees the operating system handle.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That `ConcurrentDictionary` will call the factory on multiple threads for the same key is something of a disappointment. I'll definitely have to re-visit that part of the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `Lazy<T>` for `SearchRequest.Results` maybe? But that would probably entail a bit of redesign. Haven't thought this out completely.

But what would probably be almost a drop-in replacement for your use case is to implement your own `Wait()` and `Set()` methods in `SearchRequest`. Something like:

```
object _resultLock;

void Wait()
{
  lock(_resultLock)
  {
     while (!_hasResult)
       Monitor.Wait(_resultLock);
  }
}

void Set(string results)
{
  lock(_resultLock)
  {
     Results = results;
     _hasResult = true;
     Monitor.PulseAll(_resultLock);
  }
}
```

No need to dispose. :)

Comment: I'm liking this solution. Need to give it a bit more thought, but it's looking pretty good. And I really don't need a `_hasResult`. I can just use the `Result` as in `while (Result == null)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your best bet to make this work is to use the TPL for all of you multi-threading needs. That's what it is good at.

As per my comment on your question, you need to keep in mind that `ConcurrentDictionary` does have side-effects. If multiple threads try to call `GetOrAdd` at the same time then the factory can be invoked for all of them, but only one will win. The values produced for the other threads will just be discarded, however by then the compute has been done.

Since you also said that doing searches is expensive then the cost of taking a lock ad then using a standard dictionary would be minimal.

So this is what I suggest:

```
private Dictionary<string, Task<string>> _requests
    = new Dictionary<string, Task<string>>();

public string Search(string key)
{
    Task<string> task;
    lock (_requests)
    {
        if (_requests.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            task = _requests[key];
        }
        else
        {
            task = Task<string>
                .Factory
                .StartNew(() => DoSearch(key));
            _requests[key] = task;
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                lock(_requests)
                {
                    _requests.Remove(key);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return task.Result;
}
```

This option nicely runs the search, remembers the task throughout the duration of the search and then removes it from the dictionary when it completes. All requests for the same key while a search is executing get the same task and so will get the same result once the task is complete.

I've test the code and it works.

Comment: +1. Yes, this looks very good. Thank you. I'll drop this into my project and see how it goes. Obviously, I need to look into learning a bit more about the TPL.

Comment: Yeah, that whole thing about `GetOrAdd` calling the factory multiple times is weird. That "feature" has haunted me before.

Comment: I actually ended up using the other suggestion, since I was already executing on a background thread and there wasn't a good reason to fire off another one. But your suggestion made me re-think the design of my application and allowed me to simplify it to a large extent. Thank you for the suggestion.